# How do you remove the style from a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

When using a custom graphic in [`UIBarButtonItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) inside a `UIToolbar`, the program automatically turns your graphic white and applies an inner shadow. How do I prevent this automatic styling and use my custom graphic verbatim?

[image: screenshot of toolbar]

Answer (score 1):

This is how it would normally be done:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];     
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[myButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

UIBarButtonItem *myBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someSelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(someX, someY, someWidth, someHeight)];
[self.toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:someBtnItemOne, myBtnItem, someBtnItemThree, nil]];
[myBtnItem release];
```

If this doesnt help, can you please show the code you are using to initialize the toolbar and button items?

Comment: I use Interface Builder to construct my toolbar... Questions: do the pros construct their views with code because Interface Builder is too limited?

Comment: @Jojo If you want to fine tune something then it is better to create it programatically rather then in the IB.  The IB is great for simple default views and subviews, but I would suggest at least building a few things without it; its the best way to learn and really understand what is going on "behind the scenes" of the IntrfceBldr.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a class I created that inherits from UIBarButtonItem which is image based:

```
    #import "XXBarButtonImageItem.h"

    @implementation XXBarButtonImageItem

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
                  image:(UIImage*)image 
        backgroundImage:(UIImage*)bgImage
    {
        _button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [_button setFrame:frame];

        self = [super initWithCustomView:_button];
        if (self) 
        {
            if (image)
                [_button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            if (bgImage)
                [_button setBackgroundImage:bgImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        return self;    
    }

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
                  image:(UIImage*)image 
        backgroundImage:(UIImage*)bgImage 
                 target:(id)target 
                 action:(SEL)selector
    {
        self = [self initWithFrame:frame image:image backgroundImage:bgImage];
        if (self)
        {
            [_button addTarget:target action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }

        return self;
    }

    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [super dealloc];
        [_button release];
    }

    - (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)selector forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
    {
        [_button addTarget:target action:selector forControlEvents:controlEvents];
    }

    - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
    {
        [_button setImage:image forState:state];
    }

    - (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
    {
        [_button setImage:image forState:state];
    }

    @end
```

Comment: "inherits from `UIBarButtonItem`" is synonymous with "can be passed to anything that accepts a `UIBarButtonItem`", but regardless, this is a nifty idea!  You could even make this a category for convenience.

Comment: Where's the header file? (I'm a noob)